# Choosing right set of variables for Logistic regression and decision tree

Tags: r, regression, logistic, feature-selection, churn

I am a beginner in R. I am doing logistic regression using around 80 independent variables using `glm` function in R. The dependent variable is `churn` which says whether a customer churned or not. I want to know how to identify the right combination of variables to get a good predictive logistic regression model in R.  I also want to know how to identify the same for making good decision tree in R ( I am using the `ctree` function from the `party` package).
So far, I had used `drop1` function  and  `anova(LogMdl, test="Chisq")` where `LogMdl` is my logistic regression model to drop unwanted variables in the predictive model.  But maximum accuracy I was able to achieve was only 60%.

Also I am not sure if I am using the `drop1` and `anova` functions correctly. I dropped the variables with lowest AIC using `drop1` function.  Using `anova` function, I dropped variables with p value > 0.05

Kindly help me how to identify the right set of variables for both logistic regression and decision tree models to increase my model's predictive accuracy to close to 90% or more than that if possible.

```
library(party)
setwd("D:/CIS/Project work")
CellData <- read.csv("Cell2Cell_SPSS_Data - Orig.csv")
trainData <- subset(CellData,calibrat=="1")
testData <- subset(CellData,calibrat=="0") # validation or test data set
LogMdl = glm(formula=churn ~ revenue  + mou    + recchrge+ directas+ 
               overage + roam    + changem +
               changer  +dropvce + blckvce + unansvce+ 
               custcare+ threeway+ mourec  +
               outcalls +incalls + peakvce + opeakvce+ 
               dropblk + callfwdv+ callwait+
               months  + uniqsubs+ actvsubs+  phones  + models  +
               eqpdays  +customer+ age1    + age2    + 
               children+ credita + creditaa+
               creditb  +creditc + creditde+ creditgy+ creditz + 
               prizmrur+ prizmub +
               prizmtwn +refurb  + webcap  + truck   + 
               rv      + occprof + occcler +
               occcrft  +occstud + occhmkr + occret  + 
               occself + ownrent + marryun +
               marryyes +marryno + mailord + mailres + 
               mailflag+ travel  + pcown   +
               creditcd +retcalls+ retaccpt+ newcelly+ newcelln+ 
               refer   + incmiss +
               income   +mcycle  + creditad+ setprcm + setprc  + retcall, 
               data=trainData, family=binomial(link="logit"),
               control = list(maxit = 50))
ProbMdl = predict(LogMdl, testData, type = "response")
testData$churndep = rep(0,31047)  # replacing all churndep with zero
testData$churndep[ProbMdl>0.5] = 1   # converting records with prob > 0.5 as churned
table(testData$churndep,testData$churn)  # comparing predicted and actual churn
mean(testData$churndep!=testData$churn)    # prints the error %
```

Link for documentation of variables: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9y78DHd3U-DZS05VndFV3A4Ylk/

Link for Dataset (.csv file) : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9y78DHd3U-DYm9FOV9zYW15bHM/

I could not produce the output of `dput` since the data size is more than 5 MB. So I have zipped the file and placed in the above link.

Description of important variables:
* `churn` is the variable that says whether a customer churned or not.....
* `churndep` is the variable that needs to be predicted in the test data (validation data) and has to be compared with the `churn` variable which is already populated with actual churn.
For both churn and churndep, value of 1 means churned and 0 means not churned.

Comment: answers will be of limited help unless you provide us with some reproducible code and data. Please add your code and the output of `dput(<your data set>)`.

Comment: My question is actually a question in R only.

Comment: Pls find below the R Code                                                                                                      library(party)
setwd("D:/")
CellData <- read.csv("Cell2Cell_SPSS_Data - Orig.csv")

trainData <- subset(CellData,calibrat=="1")
testData <- subset(CellData,calibrat=="0")
LogMdl = glm(formula=churn ~ ., data=trainData, family=binomial(link="logit"),control = list(maxit = 50))                                         ..... Continued in next comment

Comment: ProbMdl = predict(LogMdl, testData, type = "response")
testData$churndep = rep(0,31047)
testData$churndep[ProbMdl>0.5] = 1   # converting records with prob > 0.5 as churned
table(testData$churndep,testData$churn)
mean(testData$churndep!=testData$churn)    # prints the error %                  Link for documentation of variables: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9y78DHd3U-DZS05VndFV3A4Ylk/view?usp=sharing                                                                 .....Continued in next comment

Comment: Link for Dataset (.csv file) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9y78DHd3U-DYm9FOV9zYW15bHM/view?usp=sharing                                                                                        I could not produce the output of dput since the data size is more than 5 MB. So I have zipped the file and placed in the above link.                                      I am in desperate need of help. Thank you all for taking the time to help  answer my question. I wanted to know how to find the right set of variables using R to get maximum accuracy of prediction possible.

Comment: Have you considered choosing the variables `x` and `y`? I've seen a lot of people reporting good results for their regressions when they've chosen `x` and `y`.

Comment: I have produced my entire code above in my original post. By mistake, I included them in the comments itself.                                                                                       @prpl.mnky.dshwshr, Please clarify what do you mean by x and y variable. I have about 80 variables.

Comment: PS not a full answer, but `glm(churn ~ ., <etc>)` will fit a model using all of the variables in the data set (except the specified response variable) as predictors

Comment: @mkemp6.. As you have requested, I have provided the R code above and dataset. Kindly let me know your suggestions.                                I am in need of desperate help. So anyone who can help me, kindly let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Can you please add the extra information as an edit to the original Q?

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101003/logistic-regression-on-big-data